# How to get same rownumber() for same values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I need to get the same *row number* if the values gets repeated in column `week` and `desc`. For the following table:

| week | desc |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ff |
| 1 | ss |
| 1 | ss |
| 2 | ff |
| 2 | ss |
| 4 | ff |
| 4 | ff |
| 4 | ss |
| 4 | ss |

The expected result is:

| week | desc | rownum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ff | 1 |
| 1 | ss | 2 |
| 1 | ss | 2 |
| 2 | ff | 1 |
| 2 | ss | 2 |
| 4 | ff | 1 |
| 4 | ff | 1 |
| 4 | ss | 2 |
| 4 | ss | 2 |

Comment: How code you want the FF rows and not the ss rows as Rownum = 1?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want [`DENSE_RANK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) instead of `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT Week
     , [Desc]
     , DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Week ORDER BY [Desc]) AS [Rank #]
FROM t
```

`DENSE_RANK` and [`RANK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) assign same value to rows with tie in the order by columns. `DENSE_RANK` in addition assigns "dense" rank numbers instead of "gapped" numbers.

Comment: Good answer. You only forgot an alias for the third column. ;) But I would agree that `RowNum` might not be the best column alias for these query results.